# Why is first.split(separator: " ").map { Int(String($0))!} better than first.split(separator: " ").map { Int($0)!}?

Tags: string, performance, integer, swift5

```
import Foundation

let first = readLine()! // input : 10 20 30

processTime {
    first.split(separator: " ").map { Int($0)! }
}
processTime {
    first.split(separator: " ").map { Int(String($0))! }
}

func processTime(blockFunction: () -> ()) {
    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    blockFunction()
    let processTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    print("performance = \(processTime)")
}
```

performance = 0.0012700557708740234 => Int($0)!

performance = 0.000843048095703125  => Int(String($0))!

I used map to convert to Int. But it took less time when I converted it to "Int(String($0))!". I wonder why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `split` does not returning strings, but substrings, so the `Int($0)` rendition is converting substrings to integers, and `Int(String($0))` is converting the substring to a string, and then to an integer.

Looking at the disassembly for these two renditions, they are calling a different `Int.init?` methods. But there is a lot going on in the assembly, so it’s a little hard to say whether that’s the only difference or whether some of the other things going on in the background might have some modest impact, too.

But, it’s safe to say that converting `String` to an `Int` is more efficient than dealing with substrings. That having been said, I’d stick with the cleaner code and not worry about this negligible difference unless this difference, measured in ten thousandths of a second, are going to be material (i.e. you’re doing this millions of times, that there aren’t other things that elsewhere in the code that might have more material optimization opportunities, etc.). As Donald Knuth said:

> We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%.

---

By the way, when measuring performance, rather than measuring a single call, do it millions of times and see how they compare. Also, when testing performance, you might want to also try randomizing the order in which you do the tests, repeating it several times, to make sure the order of execution isn't impacting the performance. Finally, make sure you are testing an optimized release build, not a debug build.

Also, unit tests have a `measure` method for comparing performance, repeating the test ten times:

```
class ConversionBenchmarkTests: XCTestCase {    
    let input = "10 20 30"
    let count = 100_000

    func testInt() throws {
        measure {
            for _ in 0 ..< count {
                let result = input.split(separator: " ").map { Int($0)! }
                XCTAssertEqual(result.count, 3)
            }
        }
    }

    func testString() throws {
        measure {
            for _ in 0 ..< count {
                let result = input.split(separator: " ").map { Int(String($0))! }
                XCTAssertEqual(result.count, 3)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `String` rendition was twice as fast:

[image]